# Upgrading Solr VM - could this cause problems?

Tags: solr, lucene, jvm

I have a Solr installation running on JVM 1.6.0_18 and I would like to migrate into a much more powerful machine where it will share a 1.6.0_21 JVM with another application (Solr and the other application won't share the same Tomcat instance btw).

Will this pose any problems? Are the JVM requirements documented anywhere?

Comment: @javanna Give me a chance :) I've yet to do the migration...

Answer (score 2):

I think you will be fine. But if someone wants to upgrade it above 1.6.0_21, maybe you should go to 1.6.0_29 and not look back.

Because after _21 until _29, the code that lucene uses to read variable-length integers (used all the time in search!) is sometimes wrongly compiled by hotspot... we tried to add a hack/workaround (manually unroll it to dodge the bugs) but in general I would just avoid these versions, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2975

In response to your questions about "JVM requirements", lucene doesn't have "special" JVM requirements, only that we have lots of tests that actually execute things more than 10,000 times, and have found bugs in particular versions you should avoid, thats all.

As of posting this comment, I only know of minor issues with 1.6.0_29 and 1.7.0_01. So I would really recommend these as some major bugs previously affecting lucene are fixed there.